# Rolling sum across subsets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data set with values ('ee') of interest by quarter, and multiple fields which indicate the amount of ee in various subsets of the population, as follows:

```
test=pd.DataFrame(data={'cyq':['2018Q1']*3+['2018Q2']*3+['2018Q3']*3+['2018Q4']*3,
                   'species':['canine','canine','feline']*4,
                   'group':['a','b','a']*4,
                    'ee':range(12)})
```

I'm trying to get a rolling sum of ee over the quarters, specific to each unique subset of the other fields, in this case species, and group. In my actual data set, I have six identifying fields in total.

The following:

```
test.groupby(['cyq','species','group']).ee.rolling(window=2).sum()
```

is producing all NaNs. Other solutions which I've found end up rolling the sum within the each quarter, or only on one identifying field. My goal is to take a rolling sum that recognizes canine a, canine b, and feline a as distinct and rolls their ee values by quarter:

[image]

Thank you so much for the help. I feel like there's a simple solution, but variations on this question I've found here aren't working on my dataset.

EDIT: I've pieced together the following solution, but sure this can't be the most effective or efficient way to achieve the goal:

```
test=pd.DataFrame(data={'cyq':['2018Q1']*3+['2018Q2']*3+['2018Q3']*3+['2018Q4']*3,
                   'species':['canine','canine','feline']*4,
                   'group':['a','b','a']*4,
                    'ee':range(12)})
test['cyq']=test.cyq.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
test=test.groupby(['group','species','cyq']).sum().reset_index(level=2)
test=test.groupby(level=[i for i in range(test.index.nlevels)]).rolling('100D',min_periods=2,on='cyq').sum()
test.droplevel([i for i in range(int(test.index.nlevels/2))]).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT2**
Again, regarding to the comments, here a possible solution? Please try it on your real data and validate it.

```
test['cyq']= pd.to_datetime(test['cyq'])
test=test.set_index('cyq').groupby(['species','group']).rolling('100D',min_periods=2).sum()
```

**EDIT**
Based on your comment at the other answer I think I know what you are searching for.
The mistake was you included the quarters in your groupby which you actually don't want to.

```
test=pd.DataFrame(data={'cyq':['2018Q1']*3+['2018Q2']*3+['2018Q3']*3+['2018Q4']*3,
                   'species':['canine','canine','feline']*4,
                   'group':['a','b','a']*4,
                    'ee':range(12)})

res = test.groupby(['species', 'group'], as_index = False)['ee'].rolling(window=2).sum().join(test['cyq'])
print(res)

   species group    ee     cyq
0   canine     a   NaN  2018Q1
3   canine     a   3.0  2018Q2
6   canine     a   9.0  2018Q3
9   canine     a  15.0  2018Q4
1   canine     b   NaN  2018Q1
4   canine     b   5.0  2018Q2
7   canine     b  11.0  2018Q3
10  canine     b  17.0  2018Q4
2   feline     a   NaN  2018Q1
5   feline     a   7.0  2018Q2
8   feline     a  13.0  2018Q3
11  feline     a  19.0  2018Q4
```

You don't get any results because in your provided example after the `groupby` each group is exactly 1 row. Your rolling window is `2`. Look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) for `pd.rolling`, quote from `min_periods`.

> **min_periods** : *int, default None*
>
> Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value;
> otherwise, result is np.nan.
> For a window that is specified by an
> integer, min_periods will default to the size of the window.

Since you never have a window of two all values return `NaN`. If your real data is bigger and each group has more values, your code will work.
You could set `min_periods` to `1` so you will get a return value if there is at least one value.

Comment: Setting min_periods to 1 results in a rolling sum down the ee column without any recognition of the grouping. I do have a window of >=2 in the example above, as I have four quarters of data for each subgroup. I should be able to get a rolling sum for each of the three subgroups for Q2, Q3, and Q4.

Comment: no you don't. If you only group by quarter, then yes, you can make a rolling sum, but you groupby 3 columns. and for that, each "group" is exactly 1 item. Just to be clear what I mean. run this line: `test.groupby(['cyq','species','group']).ee.size()` it shows you the size of each group. you will see every single entry is `1`

Comment: Thanks, your comment inspired the edited solution above. I kicked cyq back out so each subset of species-group has four quarters of data, and I'm getting the correct results. But my answer seems pretty darn messy, I'd be surprised if there wasn't a more efficient way to accomplish it.

Comment: I updated my answer, have a look. There is no groupby for the `quarter`. you only have one rolling sum for the data grouped for `species` and `group` for each quarter

Comment: Brilliant, we're so close. In my messy solution above, I'm able to perform the rolling sum using a time offset just in case I'm missing any quarterly data. Can you think of any means of editing your solution above so the rolling sum rolls on the date information available in cyq?

Comment: I tried to run your solution but I get an ValueError at the line where you calulate the `100D` rolling sum. Did you run your code exactly the way you posted it in the question?

Comment: I actually just edited it to work for any number of multi-index levels. That's a direct copy-paste from the code which is working for me.

Comment: ah I got it. We have now a datetime, but your example code just repeats 3 times the 4 quarters for the year 2018 which leads to an error. Ill run it and see where your output is different from mine.

Comment: updated my answer again. If that still doesn't work please add some better example (close to your real data) with the exact desired output

Comment: You did it! I hope everyone who struggled through a futile online search similar to my own finds your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you got anything from your first code because there is nothing that would come back based on that grouping. However, I was able to get pretty close to what you were looking for by removing the grouping.

```
test=pd.DataFrame(data={'cyq':['2018Q1']*3+['2018Q2']*3+['2018Q3']*3+['2018Q4']*3,
                   'species':['canine','canine','feline']*4,
                   'group':['a','b','a']*4,
                    'ee':range(12)})
test['ee'] = test['ee'].rolling(window = 2).sum()
test
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a shot. Without the grouping, the rolling sum just occurs down the column and doesn't roll by quarter. I'm trying to get the 2018Q2 rolling sum for feline-a to be the sum of the 2018Q1 and 2018Q value for feline-a, and similarly with the other unique categories of species-group.

Comment: I understand that, but based on the provided data there isn't a single example of a grouping that would occur. Do you have more data to provide or do I not understand what you are trying to do

Comment: There are three groups above that should be able to rolling sum by quarter: canine-a, canine-b, and feline-a. For example, Canine-a's four values for the four quarters are 0, 3, 6, and 9, so I would want the rolling sum for canine-a to show NaN, 3, 9, 15.